# In Component service.ts url: "http://localhost:4200/data/products.json" not found

Tags: angular, angular-http, angular-httpclient

I am getting a 404 not found error on this line of code "return this.http.get('../data/products.json');"

where the path is "src\app\shared\services\product.service.ts" for the service.ts file. The path of the json file is "src\data\products.json"

This is the service.ts code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface Product {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  price: number;
  imageUrl: string;
  description: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAll(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>('../data/products.json');
  }

  getById(productId: number): Observable<Product> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>('../data/products.json')
      .pipe(
        map(products => <Product>products.find(p => p.id === productId))
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your json folder under an assets folder like so :

```
src\assets\mock\products.json
```

and then you modify the path in your method :

```
getAll(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>('assets/mock/products.json')
}
```